# Strokes of rectangle and pen tool line different

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am new to Photoshop. I need to make a mockup for a website. First I've drawn a rectangle 1-pixel and with pen tool a brush setting 1-pixel, but the pen tool line has more than 1-pixel and what settings do I have to change so that both elements have the same stroke?

Here are two screenshots:

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

On the shape layer the pencil has the same wrong stroke. So it has to do with the shape layer. But to do a pen tool stroke you have to add a effect stroke. The rectangle is always the same because you cant place it on the shape layer.

Here are some of the other tools I used: [Line Pixel Widths](http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/3145/jfmdah4e_png.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to just do a long click on the "Brush Tool" and change the tool to a 
"Pencil Tool" instead.

[image]

Change the size to 1px.

[image]

Another option is to use the line tool and set that to 1px as well. But this will create similar uneven transparent pixels as the brush tool. The pencil tool won't create any transparent pixels.

[image]

Here is an example of how to do it with the Path Tool in the Paths Panel. Make sure you select the Work Path and click on Stroke Path with Brush.

[image]

Edit: Clarification

Comment: I have done it also with the Pencil Tool, but the stroke is the same as with Brush Tool. Although I've set it to 1px.

Comment: With line tool it works, but maybe I have to do more elements with pen tool and to set the right stroke. I think somewhere I have a wrong setup. But I am new to Photoshop and dont know where it could be.

Comment: I tried a few different setups with the pencil tool versus the rectangle tool. One possibility is that you don't have the pencil shape set to a square. In my second image you can see that I have that first element selected.

Comment: The problem with pencil tool is that it is not easy or impossible to do straight lines. Therefore a solution with pen tool would be the best. But as I see there are no options to do a line that looks the same as the rectangle tool 1px.

Comment: Is it ok if you upload another screenshot of how it looks with the pencil tool next to the brush tool next to the rectangle tool? I think I might know what the confusion is.

Comment: Three other potential solutions that might fix this problem:

1. Use a vector program instead such as Illustrator, where the lines are not pixelated and have lossy quality. This will cause all lines to be perfect and not jagged.

2. Use the Paths panel and create the lines as a path instead of a layer, then click on "Stroke Path with Brush" (uploaded picture in answer).

3. Make the resolution of the document larger so that you can not see the jaggedness in the line visibly.

Answer (score 0):

You should state what version of Photoshop you are using.

If you want strokes to match, don't mix raster painting tools with vector drawing tools.

Draw the rectangle with the rectangle shape tool. Draw your lines with the Line Tool

[image: line tool]

Using brushes or other raster painting tools is always going to result in more anti-aliasing of the strokes. Or, in the case of the pencil, not enough anti-aliasing. That's merely the nature of those tools. If you stick to the vector tools, you will get ant-aliasing on angled paths or curves, but it will be to a lesser degree as well as offer you the ability to alter any path later should the need arise.